# Spinner App crash on opening.

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner

I am trying to make my Spinner1 change visibility on spinner2.My code compiles ok, but app crashes on opening.

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner2);

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
    {

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

        }

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int arg2, long arg3) {
            Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
            Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
            TextView textview1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

            if (spinner.getSelectedItemPosition() == 1) {
                textview1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                spinner1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Post your log cat error

Comment: My guess...you don't have a `Spinner` in your `activity_main.xml` with a resource id of `spinner2` and you're getting a `NullPointerException`. Post the `activity_main.xml`.

Comment: I have a spinner2 in my main xml.

Comment: @user1687626 : In `main.xml` or `activity_main.xml`? You're setting your view content using `R.layout.activity_main` not `R.layout.main`.

Answer (score 0):

Please dont set ID's during an event; Its simply not good; do like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    TextView textview1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);


    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
    {

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

        }

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int arg2, long arg3) {
            if (spinner.getSelectedItemPosition() == 1) {
                textview1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                spinner1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });}
```

Comment: I don't see why you consider it a problem to find views in the `onItemSelected(...)` method. Besides, the OP says the app crashes on opening not when an item is selected. Your suggested change shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: :) Me too thought the same once upon a time @Squonk, the thing is whenever a spinner is created it'll call this method, because the spinner is displating anyone item even before we're selecting dude; that means it already selects the first option and displays it as default selection

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so i fixed the initial app crash using an class to check the seleced item

main code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new checkSelectedItem());
}
```

My class:

```
public class checkSelectedItem implements OnItemSelectedListener {

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
    Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner)parent.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    TextView textview1 = (TextView)parent.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    if (pos == 1) {
        textview1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        spinner1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else {
        if ( textview1.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            textview1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        if ( spinner1.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            spinner1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }
}

public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {

}
```

So the initial crash is fixed, but now when i select the option 1 in my spinner2 the app crashes..